# How to change screen dimming time programatically in android?

Tags: android

I would like to change system dimming time in my custom application.

My device is set 30s-timeout for sleep. 
So if I am in home screen and leave it, it goes dim in 23sec and screen is turned off in 30sec.

Is there any idea for changing screen dimming time for my application?

It's ok to change framework source.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "to change framework source" do you mean change the setting for good or just make it possible to change the setting in the app of your own dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe android let's you control this option from an application. Of course it lets you set a wake lock for applications to keep the screen on, but I'm pretty sure the screen dimming or "Backlight Timeout" can only be set by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a programmatic way of modifying the system setting, but you can work around it if the current screen timeout is known...

Figure out how long you want to keep the screen on for and then subtract the current timeout seconds from that time span. The resulting number is how long you should programmatically keep it on via something like [View.keepScreenOn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29)